# Changing the Specific item text size in navigation view

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am creating a `navigation drawer` in android and I have added the items in **menu_main.xml** but I am not able to change the   `text size` of the menu Specific items. Below is the code menu_main.xml:

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/motel"
        android:title="Motel">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/packages"
        android:title="Packages">
    </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a style in themes like:

```
<style name="drawer_text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/safety_orange</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22dp</item>
</style>
```

And, in Activity:

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(null);
    navigationView.setItemTextAppearance(R.style.drawer_text);
```